# Replacing the missing values of while comparing 2 tables

Tags: python, sql, pandas, python-2.7, sqlite

I have 2 tables on my database and would like to compare both the tables and replace the missing values from one table to another. For example.

```
TABLE 1
column 1  column 2 
ab         3  
ab         -
a          1
a          -
b          -
b          2
ab         3  
ab         -
a          1
a          -
b          2

TABLE 2
column 1  column 2 
ab         3  
a          1
b          2
```

I want to compare both the tables on column 1 and replace only the missing values on column 2 and not touch the values that are already there. 
Is this possible on SQL or using pandas on python? Any solution would be helpful.

Comment: Consider table 1 as the master and table 2 as the loop up table. All I wanted to do was to look up table 1 and replace the significant values on table 1. There are not always 2 rows of every thing. I have edited that bit. To give you more context table  1 has a few million rows and table 2 has the look ups for them. Please do let me know if this answers your questions.

Comment: Makes sense - I think the two answers below will achieve that.

Answer (score -2):

```
## SQL Query be like ##
```

### This query replaces the column2 value of Table2 to the column2 of Table1 which are NULL.

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.Col2=table2.Col2
FROM table1
JOIN table2 
ON table1.col1=table2.col1
where table1.col2 IS NULL
```

Comment: Please add some context.

Comment: This query replaces the column2 value of Table2 to the column2 of Table1 which are NULL.  @MatthieuBrucher

Comment: Please put this in your answer. It should be self-consistent.

Comment: Would you know how you would write it in sqlite? @Md.MehediHassan

Comment: Sorry buddy, I'm not working in sqlite yet @MatthieuBrucher